# CSS3 - trigger transition of a div with a click on a link

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am currently working with CSS3 transitions and animations for an university project.

I need to make a `div` appear (from `opacity:0.5` to `opacity:1`) when I click on a link on the page.

I was using the information found in [this article](http://tangledindesign.com/how-to-trigger-css3-transitions-on-click-using-target/) to reach my goal, but it seems to not work with the `<div>`.

Here's my code:

**CSS**

```
.crea_account{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#0F0;
    border-radius:5%;
    width:600px;
    height:300px;
    top: 250px;
    right: 135px;
    padding: 10px;
    opacity:0.5;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
}

:target{
    opacity:1;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="benvenuto">
        <h1 class="welcome"><a href="#">Benvenuto!</a></h1>
        <h2 class="login cool_link"><a href="#crea_account">Crea il tuo account</a>      oppure <a href="#">Accedi</a></h2>
</div>
<div class="crea_account">
    Some content
</div>
```

Do someone have the link of any tutorial that explain what I want to obtain?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a live example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the hash `#` to link to an element, you have to set the `id` of the target to that value. The class doesn't affect this at all.

```
<div id="crea_account" class="crea_account">
    Some content
</div>
```

Each `id` is unique in each document. The hash part of the url refers to that specific element with the given `id` and that's where the browser wants to jump to. (Also the `:target` should work if you're in a modern browser)

Comment: Even if I substitute the class with the id, I can't get the result I want. I can't understand, in the link I provided in the description the method works for the paragraph, but not for the div??

Comment: EDIT: Now it works!!! I simply added #crea_account:target{opacity:1;
} in the css, and in the div i have left only the id, not the class! Thank you